# Android UP button goes to mainActivity instead of current

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I have 3 activities:

- MainActivity (start activity with grid view)
- FragmentActivity (full screen image slider accessed from grid view)
- InfoActivity (blank activity opened from menu in either Main or Fragment)

When I go from MainActivity to InfoActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, InfoActivity.class));
```

and press the "up" button I get back to main activity.

When I go from FragmentActivity to InfoActivity

```
 startActivity(new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class));
```

and press the "up" I STILL get back to MainActivity.

I know it's because my MainActivity is the parent of Info.

But how do I make the "up" behave like the "back" button, so that I can go from InfoActivity to FragmentActivity?

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override `onOptionsItemSelected` in the `InfoActivity` class to intercept the `"up"` button and call `onBackPressed` from there. Like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @Firoze Rakib will work but I would like to provide you better understanding of the problem and solution advised by Google.

First of all you most probably have defined parent in your AndroidManifest.xml, you should remove it since your InfoActivity can have different parents.

Secondly, there is a small difference between BACK BUTTON(which is programatically called in @Firoze answer) and UP BUTTON. First one simply destroy current activity and show activity that was previously shown, theoretically it does not have to be any of your parents. The UP BUTTON starts new instance of the parent Activity and clear the activity stack in the current task.

If this difference matters for you then you should follow instructions from [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home). Take a look at second point that starts with this sentence:

> Or, override getSupportParentActivityIntent() and
>   onCreateSupportNavigateUpTaskStack() in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

> how do i make the "up" behave like the "back" button...

I believe another answer has the technical details if you are determined to do this (which you should not).

The purpose of my answer is to point out that making up behave like back will confuse users by violating the [Android design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html).

Up navigation is an alternative to using the back key with a different purpose: it gives the user a way to navigate back to the top of an app when they are "lost" deep in a hierarchy and they might have to press the back key many times to escape. In this situation some users will panic and start mashing the back key, and up nav is meant to give them an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if(item != null )
if( && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
// your code 
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```